# How to check if token contains malicious code that transfers ownership of wallet?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, etherscan, security, erc-721

There is a general scam going around this year where unsolicited ERC-721 (NFT) minting contracts, or ERC-20 token contracts, if interacted with by a victim, allows an exploit where the victim's interacting wallet will approve the scammers for ownership and access of their wallet, resulting in draining of funds and assets.

How to detect this in the code of a minting or token contract beforehand on Etherscan? What is the malicious one-liner of Solidity code or script that engages this exploit?

Comment: Can you provide any link to the documented scam or an occurrence of it?

Comment: Don't know a specific case, but know it's happening